# Не работает .htaccess на localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc, config

**Проверяю работоспособность mod_rewrite?**

Создаю на сервере пустую поддиректорию mod_rewrite_test/ и загружаю в нее файлы .htaccess и index.php следующего содержания:

***.htaccess:***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

***index.php:***

```
<?php
    print 'mod_rewrite works!';
?>
```

Набераю в браузере адрес вида http://localhost:8080/mod_rewrite_test/check.
На открывшейся странице в браузере должна появиться надпись «**mod_rewrite works!**», но вместо нее появляется **404 ошибка**.

Подозреваю что сервер не поддерживает.htaccess.

**Вопрос:** как сделать чтобы всё работало?

***Дополнение:*** *Практикую на Android с программой WebServer PHP/MyAdmin/MySQL*

***localhost_host.conf***

```
server {
#begin_port (do not remove this label!)
listen 8080;
#end_port (do not remove this label!)

#begin_hostname (do not remove this label!)
server_name localhost;
#end_hostname (do not remove this label!)

#begin_docroot (do not remove this label!)
root /mnt/sdcard/htdocs;
#end_docroot (do not remove this label!)

#location /admin/ {
#   auth_basic "Admin Zone";
#   auth_basic_user_file /data/data/com.nokshaserv/components/etc/.pass;
#}

index  index.html index.htm index.php;

#   location @rewrite {
#   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
#   }

#   location / {
#   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
#   }

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {

}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/data/data/com.nokshaserv/tmp/php.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9786;
    include  /mnt/sdcard/kickwebinfo/conf/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас стоит веб сервер Apache? По конфигу видно, что используете Nginx + phpfpm

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере конфига для веб-сервера Nginx видно, что он проксирует на php-fpm, а файлы `.htaccess` являются конфигурационными только для веб-сервара `Apache`, который у вас не установлен. Вам нужно править конфиг `localhost_host.conf`.

Перевести апачевский конфиг на конфиг для Nginx может помочь сайт https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess

Comment: В .conf дописываю # nginx
configuration location /«/storage/emulated/0/htdocs/mod_rewrite_test/» {
allow all; 
} но ничего не помогает

Comment: @soulwolf не очень понял, что вы прописываете. Давайте лучше поймем, чего вы хотите добиться? И действительно ли у вас запущен Nginx

Comment: нужно чтобы код перенаправлял обработку всех страниц на index.php (Front Controller). Стоит Nginx 1.5.11

Comment: @soulwolf исходя из вашего конфига, у вас так и должно работать. Сейчас все запросы будут идти к `fastcgi_index`

Comment: тогда я вообще не понимаю по каким причинам можете не работать :(

Comment: @soulwolf все ваши запросы идет на файл index.php в корне веб директории

Comment: Перенес проект на Apache всё работает , на nginx не могу настроить